# Problem with installation of vegan package - cannot find -lgfortran

Tags: r, vegan

I was installing another package called vcfR where it says vegan is source package and needs to be installed, then it showed errors when installing. So I decided to install vegan package first.

This is an online R studio, the package I need to analyse is too big to be done on my laptop. The online R studio is by my school server, which was in-built in a ssh server account.

below is the error message:

````
Installing package into ‘/home/joyzheng/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vegan_2.5-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2074611 bytes (2.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘vegan’ ...
** package ‘vegan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c data2hill.c -o data2hill.o
gfortran  -fpic  -g -O2  -c decorana.f -o decorana.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c getF.c -o getF.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c goffactor.c -o goffactor.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran  -fpic  -g -O2  -c monoMDS.f -o monoMDS.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c nestedness.c -o nestedness.o
gfortran  -fpic  -g -O2  -c ordering.f -o ordering.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c pnpoly.c -o pnpoly.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c stepacross.c -o stepacross.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c vegdist.c -o vegdist.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o vegan.so data2hill.o decorana.o getF.o goffactor.o init.o monoMDS.o nestedness.o ordering.o pnpoly.o stepacross.o vegdist.o -L/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/lib -lRlapack -L/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [vegan.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vegan’
* removing ‘/home/joyzheng/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/vegan’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vegan’ had non-zero exit status```
````

Comment: Perhaps installing gfortran would solve the issue? https://fortran-lang.org/learn/os_setup/install_gfortran

Comment: It looks as though `gfortran` is installed, but there's something wrong with the installation.  You need to use the same tools as were used when R was built.  How did you install R?

Comment: This is an online R studio, the package I need to analyse is too big to be done on my laptop. The online R studio is by my school server, which was in-built in a ssh server account.

Comment: This is an error from linker (`ld`) which is unable to find the `gfortran` library. Somewhere in this linker command should be `-L/opt/path/to/your/gfortran/lib -lgfortran` (change to match your system) or the definition of the place where to find the files that are needed  for linking fortran objects. Your R installation should set this automatically, but you may haver installed fortran in a way that is unknown to R.

Comment: The linker flags needed for Fortran code are in R environmental variable `FLIBS`.  You can see its contents in command line with `R CMD config FLIBS`. This should contain entries with switch `-L` giving the path to needed Fortran libraries. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html for customizing `FLIBS` (e.g., with `config.site` file).

Comment: Thank you so much! this seems to be a bit out of my capability... I'll try it later

Comment: You seem to have some kind of Linux. In Linux systems the installation should take care that links are correct. However, in R it is essential that the Fortran compiler is the same as used in building R. Your commands have links to `/opt` directory which is not where development tools of R normally reside. If you have used packaged R, you should also install R development tools: r-base-dev in Debian/Ubuntu, R-core-devel in Fedora/RH/SuSE and these will set everything OK. Your commands work if you built R locally from the source with same `/opt` tools